# Image's IsLoading property is stuck

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

I've got a problem with the `Image` object on UWP.
It's IsLoading property refuses to go to `False` once the image has been loaded thus the ActivityIndicator's `IsRunning` property stays on...

The exact same piece of code works on Android emulator

```
 <StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator
        IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference Img},Path=IsLoading}"
        IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference Img},Path=IsLoading}"
        />

    <Image
        x:Name="Img"
        Source="https://unsplash.it/1980/1080/?random"/>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [known issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/commit/cdc405512844671bc3b2c8bd28f583036e5530a2) in Xamarin.uwp. You could see that official has already handle the issue in last [commit](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/commit/cdc405512844671bc3b2c8bd28f583036e5530a2). But the latest nuget package has not released. You could keep an eye on the releasing date of the latest version.

```
protected virtual async Task TryUpdateSource()
{
    // By default we'll just catch and log any exceptions thrown by UpdateSource so we don't bring down
    // the application; a custom renderer can override this method and handle exceptions from
    // UpdateSource differently if it wants
    try
    {
        await UpdateSource().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Warning(nameof(ImageRenderer), "Error loading image: {0}", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        ((IImageController)Element)?.SetIsLoading(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Going to wait for the nuget package then... Thanks !